# How do I change the screensaver programmatically?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-screensaver

I'd like to change the current Screensaver for a custom one (which I previously loaded as a resource in Visual Studio) using C#. How could that be done? I've looked for it on Google and SO, but it all talks about "How to create a Screensaver", not "How to change a Screensaver". If possible, it should work on WinXP, Vista and 7.

Comment: This one could be useful:
http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/263953-setting-up-screensaver-via-csharp-c-application
You need to do it through registry

Comment: Thanks for your link. That eased the steps. However, it doesn't work for Windows XP (in Win7 it works like a charm). Do you know anything about that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll answer my question with the piece of code that worked to me:

```
public sealed class Screensaver
{
    Screensaver() { }

    const int SPI_SETSCREENSAVEACTIVE = 0x0011;

    [DllImport("user32", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
    unsafe public static extern short SystemParametersInfo (int uiAction, int uiParam, int* pvParam, int fWinIni);

    public static void Set(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            RegistryKey oKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel",
            true);
            oKey = oKey.OpenSubKey("desktop", true);
            oKey.SetValue("SCRNSAVE.EXE", path);
            oKey.SetValue("ScreenSaveActive", "1");

            unsafe
            {
                int nX = 1;
                SystemParametersInfo(
                SPI_SETSCREENSAVEACTIVE,
                0,
                &nX,
                0
                );
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when calling it from my application:

```
static string ResourcePath(string resource)
{
    return Application.StartupPath + "\\Resources\\" + resource;
}

Program.Screensaver.Set(Program.ResourcePath("svr1.scr"));
```

I read somewhere I should write a name no longer than 8 characters (a bit weird, but XP is all like this), so my screensaver is called `svr1.scr` (not really object oriented, but does the trick)

Comment: Ugly, but I can't find a better solution. `InstallScreenSaver` in `desk.cpl` displays the control panel UI afterwards, and `SystemParametersInfo` seems to not expose that feature.

Answer (score 1):

This is the command that windows executes when installing a new one

```
rundll32.exe desk.cpl,InstallScreenSaver %l
```