# How do you install a screensaver programatically with NSIS in Windows XP, 2000, Vista and 7?

Tags: windows, installation, nsis, screensaver

Solutions I've already tried that have not worked are:

1)  Add ini key to $WINDIR\system.ini

```
[boot]
SCRNSAVE.EXE $SYSDIR\savername.scr
```

2) Call user32.dll::SystemParametersInfo(17, 1, 0, 2)

The above works in XP but not in 2000

```
rundll32.exe desk.cpl,InstallScreenSaver <path to screensaver>
```

This kind of works in 2000 but it pops up a configuration dialog and then when I go back into the dialog the settings are gone.

Looking for a solution or set of solutions that works on all platforms, does not pop up a configuration screen, retains the settings when you open the configuration dialog and doesn't require third-party software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked was combining the INI method and the registry method found here: [How do I change the screensaver programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383589/how-do-i-change-the-screensaver-programatically).  Here is the NSIS code:

```
!include WinVer.nsh

; Install the executable
${If} ${AtMostWinXP}
  SetOutPath "$SYSDIR"
  File screen.scr
${EndIf}
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
File screen.scr

; Set screensaver and make it active
${If} ${AtMostWinXP}
  WriteINIStr "$WINDIR\system.ini" "boot" "SCRNSAVE.EXE" "$SYSDIR\screen.scr"

${Else}
  WriteRegStr HKCU "Control Panel\desktop" "SCRNSAVE.EXE" "$INSTDIR\screen.scr"
  WriteRegStr HKCU "Control Panel\desktop" "ScreenSaveActive" "1"
${EndIf}

; Notify system of the change
System::Call 'user32.dll::SystemParametersInfo(17, 1, 0, 2)'
```

Notice that I install the screensaver both in \windows\system32 and in the package install directory.  For some reason installing in system32 did not work in Windows 2000.