# c# winform show after workstation lock

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I am working with Winforms screensaver application .NET 3.5 and all goes fine except locking the workstation. Application is running fine in background (login panel is over) but I want to show Winform after specified time for user. Any ideas?

Comment: Surely setting it as the system/lock screen screen saver will do? Note that normally the automatic lock occurs AFTER the screensaver is dismissed.

Comment: Yes i was thinking about this earlier. I'm thinking that I will not have the opportunity to manipulate with system lock/unlock because of customer safety reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a time stamp , using a timer control .

Ex-

After 60 Seconds initializing the WinForm Execute the Timer Command

Comment: I am able to detect locking the computer and app goes fine with timer, but when user lock the screen, app is running in background under the log panel, so we can't see it.

Comment: In my solution Windows service execute Winform DLL where is a loop that changes content of the main form (in timer loop). The whole solution is quite advanced. I tried    this.TopMost = true;
            this.Focus();
            //this.BringToFront();  at the main form but this solution doesnt work. I cant show my screensaver over log in screen...

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to run my application in user session.I have to put my application into registry 
[How do I change the screensaver programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383589/how-do-i-change-the-screensaver-programatically)
http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/screensaver/screensaver.html