# Silently set the screensaver on Windows from the command line?

Tags: windows, screensaver, windows-screensaver

I know that if you run:

```
rundll32.exe desk.cpl,InstallScreenSaver toasters.scr
```

you can set the screensaver to `toasters.scr` but it also opens up the screensaver configuration dialog. Is there a way to set the screensaver on Windows without opening any dialog by running a command?

Comment: Do you have good intentions or bad intentions?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I have good intentions. I'm developing Dashman (https://dashman.tech) and the main use of it is a screensaver, so, during the installation, I want to give the option to set it as default, but the dialog is a bit confusing.

Comment: I see, that seems fair. Still, I suspect there is no documented way of doing this. A quick Google search for "Windows set screensaver programmatically" gives a few hints, though. Since the installer probably is running with elevated privileges, these might actually work.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: I'm happy with undocumented ones ;)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd405477(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @pupeno Have you looked at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383589/how-do-i-change-the-screensaver-programatically

Comment: You want to avoid UAC protection? Or it doesn't matters?

Comment: @MaciejPulikowski: I'm not trying to circumvent security protections, so, it doesn't matter if it hits UAC or not. I guess in most cases it wouldn't as it's the user's screensaver.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have found two ways to do it:

1) Add in registry, make sure is active and setTimeOut (only minutes)

### CMD

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v SCRNSAVE.EXE /t REG_SZ /d C:\Windows\System32\Mystify.scr /f
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v ScreenSaveActive /t REG_SZ /d 1 /f
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v ScreenSaveTimeOut /t REG_SZ /d 60 /f
```

### JAVA

```
setScreenSaver(true, 1, "C:\\Windows\\System32\\Mystify.scr");

/**
 * set screen saver active, timeout and scr, only works in Windows
 * @param isActive
 * @param timeOutMin only minutes
 * @param pathToScr path to scr
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static void setScreenSaver(boolean isActive, int timeOutMin, String pathToScr) throws IOException{
    String _isActive = isActive ? "1" : "0";
    //only works with minutes, min. 1 min
    String _timeOut = timeOutMin > 1 ? timeOutMin*60+"" : "60";
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "reg", "add", "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Control Panel\\Desktop", "/v", "SCRNSAVE.EXE", "/t", "REG_SZ", "/d", pathToScr,"/f" });
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "reg", "add", "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Control Panel\\Desktop", "/v", "ScreenSaveActive", "/t", "REG_SZ", "/d", _isActive,"/f" });
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "reg", "add", "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Control Panel\\Desktop", "/v", "ScreenSaveTimeOut", "/t", "REG_SZ", "/d", _timeOut,"/f" });
}
```

2) Get path from registry and rewrite scr file, but if is set to null, you can't do it.

Comment: That looks very good. I'm going to be trying it later today or tomorrow. Please, bear with me while I deal with some emergencies.

Comment: @pupeno, I am surprised because you mentioned that you are running `rundll32.exe desk.cpl,InstallScreenSaver toasters.scr`, so you already knew how to do run a command in Java. And this answer added a cosmetic patch to mine. This is not two ways, this is just approach 1 and how to execute it in Java. I didn't post that in my answer because the critical part your problem and the solution was `reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v SCRNSAVE.EXE /t REG_SZ /d C:\Windows\system32\toasters.scr /f` and the original question was about screensaver only, not timeouts

Comment: @TarunLalwani Your method don't check if screensaver is turned on, timeout is extra. It didn't worked for me, i had "ScreenSaveActive" set to 0.  I added Java code, because i implemented this function to my app Remote Administration Tool (RAT) to manage computers in company. So i just shared it. Second method is to rewrite existing .scr file, it is not a Java code. Btw. good job for top1 Quarter.

Comment: `It didn't worked for me, i had "ScreenSaveActive" set to 0`, that's what I would have loved to hear earlier :-). Appreciate the clarification. And also `2) Get path from registry and rewrite scr file, but if is set to null, you can't do it.` did you mean overwrite the screensaver itself?

Comment: I mean to overwrite already used scr. But you will need to take ownership of the file using a administrator account.

Comment: Why these values are in string format?

Answer (score 11):

### The modern way, with powershell

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop" -Name ScreenSaveActive -Value 1
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop" -Name ScreenSaveTimeOut -Value 60
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop" -Name scrnsave.exe -Value "c:\windows\system32\mystify.scr"
```

You can put these in a `ScrnInstaller.ps1` script that you execute with the command:

```
$ powershell -WindowStyle hidden -f "ScrnInstaller.ps1"
```

**NB:** Thoses parameters are superseeded by group policy parameters (eg., to force a screen saver for users in an enterprise). You have several ways to force it [here](https://computerstepbystep.com/force-specific-screen-saver.html).

### With user / domain / site awareness: group policy

Using powershell and group policy, you can manage for which **Organizational Unit / Domain / Site**  you're affecting the change, and it's having prevedence over user settings.

Changing group policy in the case of the screen saver time out:

```
Get-Command -Module GroupPolicy
New-GPO -Name "ScreenSaverTimeOut" -Comment "Sets the time to 900 seconds"
Set-GPRegistryValue -Name "ScreenSaverTimeOut" -Key "HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop" -ValueName ScreenSaveTimeOut -Type DWord -Value 900
New-GPLink -Name "ScreenSaverTimeOut" -Target "ou=MyOU,dc=myenterprise,dc=com"
gpupdate /force /target:computer
```

for myenterprise.com. For New-GPLink parameters: [msdn reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/grouppolicy/new-gplink?view=winserver2012r2-ps)

Then you can review your GP:

```
Get-GPO -Name "ScreenSaverTimeOut" | Get-GPOReport -ReportType HTML -Path $Home\report.html
Invoke-Item $Home\report.html
```

Comment: if you don't see registry settings applied, run `rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters`

Comment: Weirdly, I had to run that UpdatePerUserSystemParameters call ~twice~ to have it update. Win10, 21H2. Even then it still didn't update sometimes in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running that command you should just run the command

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v SCRNSAVE.EXE /t REG_SZ /d C:\Windows\system32\toasters.scr /f
```

This will update the screensaver

Answer (score 0):

```
c:\Windows\System32\scrnsave.scr -start
```

The above live in a batch file will start the blank screen saver.
Pros;
Replacing scrnsave.scr with one of the other 5 screensavers in C:\Windows\system32\ will work just as well.
You will not need to restart your system and it will start right up.
Cons;
I don't know how to set the timeout. I suspect there would be an argument for the line like `c:\Windows\System32\scrnsave.scr /ScreenSaveTimeOut = 150 -start`
I think there needs to be a separate batch file to stop the screen saver.